# How do I test Sveltekit backend?

Tags: testing, sveltekit

So if I were testing individual components or functions I could use Vitest. If I were testing events happening in the browser I could use Playwright. But if I'm testing my Sveltekit backend, what do I use? For example, I add data to locals inside my handle hook and I want to make sure that the right data is being passed when my +page.server.ts runs.